# How add html to ckeditor's custom plugin?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, ckeditor.net

I have written my own custom plugin for inserting HTML in CKEDITOR. I enable the drop-down in toolbar .but I don't know how I put this HTML to ckeditor's custom plugin?

```
<div class="standardcolor">
    <div class="titlecolor">Standard Colors</div>
    <span class="color empty" data-color='ffffff'></span>                           
    <span class="color" style="background: #f5a623" data-color='f5a623'></span>
    <span class="color" style="background: #f8e71c" data-color='f8e71c'></span>                           
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it a CKEditor 4 question or CKEditor 5 question? These two are two different editing frameworks.

Comment: it is a CKEditor 4.6.2 question/